# Setting proper transparency for MultiLine?

Tags: qgis, line, style, transparency-opacity

How can you avoid faulty transparency with overlapping line segments points in styling?

I have one layer consisting of multilines. I use QGIS 3.0+.

[image]

Comment: It looks like there are two layers, but what I understand from the title, there is one layer?

Comment: yes, it is one layer consiting of multilines

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is here - please click 'edit' and explain what you're expecting and what's problematic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the opacity at a layer level. So it will be applied to the layer as a whole.

[image]

Comment: good idea, i played around with the over all opacity and the specific opacity of the line itself. did the trick. more of a workaround but satisfying.

Comment: The only downside to this is IIRC it will force your maps to be exported as raster, which can be an issue for PDFs.

Comment: You would have to anyway with the outer glow effect. But fair point.